# Calculate DigestValue and SignatureValue in XML metadata for SSO for Coldfusion applications

Tags: xml, single-sign-on, metadata

I am integrating Single-sign-on service for array of cold-fusion applications. I am not able to comprehend what is DigestValue and SignatureValue in Service Provider metadata and how to generate both. Please help me regarding this.

Thank you.
Amith

Comment: hi @amith, I've try to integrate sso in my application. ive face lot of issue If have any docs suggesed plz